# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined - highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i am trying to draw HighCharts - Polar wind Rose Chart

ref :http://www.highcharts.com/demo/polar-wind-rose

but the charts doesnt get draw when i check console of my chrome i found this error
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined**

Couldnt able to get why this is coming

My JS Code :

```
function createWindRoseChart(divID, tableID, graphTitle) {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        data: {
            table: tableID,
            startRow: 1,
            endRow: 10,
            endColumn: 8
        },
        chart: {
            polar: true,
            type: 'column',
            renderTo: divID,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)'
        },

        title: {
            text: graphTitle
        },

        subtitle: {

        },

        pane: {
            size: '85%'
        },

        legend: {
            reversed: true,
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 100,
            layout: 'vertical'
        },

        xAxis: {
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on'
        },

        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            endOnTick: false,
            showLastLabel: true,
            title: {
                text: 'Frequency (%)'
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.value + '%';
                }
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '%',
            followPointer: true
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                shadow: false,
                groupPadding: 0,
                pointPlacement: 'on'
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Its Calling function

```
createWindRoseChart('divCRATicketType', 'freq', 'Calls Open');
```

HTML Table for Creating Wind Rose Chart

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table id='freq' border='1' cellpadding='5' align='center'>
            <tr align='center'><th class='freq'>CRA</th><th class='freq'>FLM</th><th class='freq'>SLM</th><th class='freq'>Network</th><th class='freq'>UPS</th><th class='freq'>Electrical</th><th class='freq'>Power Failure</th><th class='freq'>Bank</th><th class='freq'>Cashout</th></tr>
            <tr align='center'><td class='dir'>SIS</td><td class='data'>2</td><td class='data'>1</td><td class='data'>0</td><td class='data'>0</td><td class='data'>0</td><td class='data'>1</td><td class='data'>0</td><td class='data'>0</td></tr>
            <tr align='center'><td class='dir'>S&IB</td><td class='data'>2</td><td class='data'>0</td><td class='data'>0</td><td class='data'>0</td><td class='data'>0</td><td class='data'>0</td><td class='data'>0</td><td class='data'>0</td></tr>
            <tr align='center'><td class='dir'>Branch</td><td class='data'>1</td><td class='data'>1</td><td class='data'>0</td><td class='data'>0</td><td class='data'>0</td><td class='data'>0</td><td class='data'>0</td><td class='data'>0</td></tr>
            <tr align='center'><td class='dir'>Securitrans</td><td class='data'>45</td><td class='data'>13</td><td class='data'>4</td><td class='data'>1</td><td class='data'>6</td><td class='data'>4</td><td class='data'>1</td><td class='data'>0</td></tr>
            <tr align='center'><td class='dir'>Writer</td><td class='data'>33</td><td class='data'>8</td><td class='data'>5</td><td class='data'>0</td><td class='data'>4</td><td class='data'>0</td><td class='data'>4</td><td class='data'>1</td></tr>
            <tr align='center'><td class='dir'>CMS</td><td class='data'>86</td><td class='data'>23</td><td class='data'>6</td><td class='data'>12</td><td class='data'>5</td><td class='data'>13</td><td class='data'>4</td><td class='data'>7</td></tr>
            <tr align='center'><td class='dir'>SDB CISCO</td><td class='data'>20</td><td class='data'>5</td><td class='data'>1</td><td class='data'>0</td><td class='data'>3</td><td class='data'>6</td><td class='data'>3</td><td class='data'>1</td></tr>
            <tr align='center'><td class='dir'>Brinks</td><td class='data'>27</td><td class='data'>5</td><td class='data'>2</td><td class='data'>2</td><td class='data'>0</td><td class='data'>0</td><td class='data'>7</td><td class='data'>1</td></tr>
            <tr align='center'><td class='dir'>Secure Value</td><td class='data'>30</td><td class='data'>8</td><td class='data'>1</td><td class='data'>1</td><td class='data'>2</td><td class='data'>3</td><td class='data'>7</td><td class='data'>0</td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: there is not a div of id `divCRATicketType`, you either need to create one or remove the line `renderTo: divID,`

Comment: i am passing `divCRATicketType` to `divID` in function ...and then assigning to it as `renderTo`

Comment: yes, but there is no `<div id="divCRATicketType" />` in your html markup here

Comment: Its Present in my mark up ....above html code is for creating highcharts and it is generated dynamically...

Comment: it's not clear where your code throws the error. please provide more code, the actual line that fails and remove unnecessary code (just like the `renderTo`) to narrow down what makes to code to break

Comment: Here's a fiddle with your code that kinda works:  http://jsfiddle.net/HeRPW/,  the above error is not thrown.

Comment: Post it as answer i ll mark it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a proper `polar` chart with your data:

[image]

Fiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ADhNZ/).